# expressjs get sections of url between slashes

Tags: node.js, express

If I setup a simple server using express for node.js listening on port `80` as follows:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    //mystuff
}
```

Imagine I trigger this function by going to `http://www.myapp.com/first/second/third`

How could I get the sections of the url between the slashes and put them in some format (array of strings). So I can get `["first", "second", "third"]`

Thanks!

Comment: `req.url.split('/')`?

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much. It works a little better with `req.url.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '').split('/')` (removing any leading or trailing slashes). Would you like to post as an answer so I can mark your's as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
req.url.split('/')
```

*Some another letters to minimal 30 symbols.*

Answer (score 2):

split them with / and split will return an array

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
var sections = req.url.split('/');
console.log(sections);
}
```